# Any way to suppress auto-created activity stream entries in Connections?

Tags: java, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

In IBM Connections, when the REST API is used to perform various application actions, Connections automatically creates activity-stream entries saying what happened.

Is there any way to prevent the creation of the activity-stream entries each time specific actions are performed?
More importantly for my use case, can auto-created activity-stream entries be prevented when performing actions via the Social Business Toolkit (SBT) Java API?

Here's a specific example using the SBT Java API:
If I call `ActivityService.addMember(String,Member)` to add a member to an activity, an activity-stream entry like this automatically appears in the "Discover" feed, and the new member sees similar entries in their "I'm Following" and "My Notifications" feeds:

```
  <My name> added <new member name> to the <activity name> activity.
```

That's three activity-stream entries that I want to suppress every time I call `ActivityService.addMember(String,Member)`, **but** if any user adds an activity member through the Connections default UI (which will not call my code), those activity-stream entries must appear as normal.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: I am not aware that we permit that to happen.  basically it gets put on a bus. I do know we allow people to customize the updates, perhaps if you created an invalid string it'd keep that particular update from happening

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think customising the updates can help, since we want those updates to be unaffected if done through the normal UI.